# Tcl error in doing sum

Tags: tcl

I want to compute average on a list of numbers stored in a tcl list P. Here's my script :

```
set sum 0.0
foreach e $P { set sum [expr {$sum + $e}] }
set avg [expr {1.0*$sum / [llength $P]}]
```

But I have the error : `can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"`
How can I do the sum ?

Comment: What is P? Supposedly there are not properly formatted numbers for the interpreter to understand them as numbers. You could maybe use `if {[catch {set sum [expr {$sum + $e}]}]} {puts "$e is not a number"}` in the loop instead of the current line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably due to some element in `P` not being a number. In any case, this is how you calculate average:

```
package require math::statistics
::math::statistics::mean $P
```

assuming `P` is a list of numbers.

If you have a list of data items and want to know if any of them are unsuitable for `expr` arithmetic you can do something like this:

```
foreach n $data {
    if {![string is double -strict $n]} {
        error "$n is not a number"
    }
}
```

This will report the first non-number. The `string is double` command recognizes both integers and floating point numbers<sup>1</sup>. If you leave out the `-strict` flag, the empty string will be considered a number (`expr` will still choke on it, though<sup>2</sup>).

This will give you the sublist of all non-number items in `$data`:

```
lmap n $data { 
    if {![string is double -strict $n]} {set n} continue
}
```

And this will give you the sublist of all proper-number items in `$data`:

```
lmap n $data { 
    if {[string is double -strict $n]} {set n} continue
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> the name "double" indicates that it returns true for any string that can be translated to the C data type `double`, which refers specifically to storage of a *double precision floating point number*, (an industry standard for encoding floating-point numbers). If you don't know what that is, you can pretend that it means double as in "both numbers that look like integers and numbers that look like reals".

<sup>2</sup> `expr` will also choke on the value `NaN` which is a perfectly valid floating point value, it just stands for "not a number".

Documentation: [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [error](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/error.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [math::statistics](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/statistics.html) package, [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Indeed, I had non-numeric elements in P !

Comment: @dada, don't forget to accept this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers